# Simple counterexample to sampling theorem

Tags: sampling

I know this [has to be wrong](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem), but can't see what is wrong with it:

Take a simple sinusoid. It crosses zero every half cycle. Sample it at double its frequency. If the samples coincide with the zero-crossings, you get all samples at zero. In that case, you cannot know the sinusoid's amplitude from the samples.

Anybody could spot where my mistake is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is stated in the article: "Modern statements of the theorem are sometimes careful, explicitly stating that $x(t)$ must contain no sinusoidal component at exactly frequency $B$, or that $B$ must be strictly less than half the sample rate."